# Appending to lists within loops in Python3 (again)

Tags: python, python-3.x, append, nested-lists

I'm having difficulty adding to a list iteratively.

Here's a MWE:

```
# Given a nested list of values, or sets
sets = [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 4], [1, 2, 5]]
    
# add a value to each sublist giving the number of that set in the list.
n_sets = len(sets)
for s in range(n_sets):
    (sets[s]).insert(0, s)

# Now repeat those sets reps times
reps = 4
expanded_sets = [item for item in sets for i in range(reps)]

# then assign a repetition number to each occurance of a set.
rep_list = list(range(reps)) * n_sets
for i in range(n_sets * reps):
    (expanded_sets[i]).insert(0, rep_list[i])
    
expanded_sets
```

which returns

```
[[3, 2, 1, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3],
 [3, 2, 1, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3],
 [3, 2, 1, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3],
 [3, 2, 1, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3],
 [3, 2, 1, 0, 1, 1, 2, 4],
 [3, 2, 1, 0, 1, 1, 2, 4],
 [3, 2, 1, 0, 1, 1, 2, 4],
 [3, 2, 1, 0, 1, 1, 2, 4],
 [3, 2, 1, 0, 2, 1, 2, 5],
 [3, 2, 1, 0, 2, 1, 2, 5],
 [3, 2, 1, 0, 2, 1, 2, 5],
 [3, 2, 1, 0, 2, 1, 2, 5]]
```

instead of the desired

```
[[0, 0, 1, 2, 3],
 [1, 0, 1, 2, 3],
 [2, 0, 1, 2, 3],
 [3, 0, 1, 2, 3],
 [0, 1, 1, 2, 4],
 [1, 1, 1, 2, 4],
 [2, 1, 1, 2, 4],
 [3, 1, 1, 2, 4],
 [0, 2, 1, 2, 5],
 [1, 2, 1, 2, 5],
 [2, 2, 1, 2, 5],
 [3, 2, 1, 2, 5]]
```

Just for fun, the first loop returns an expected value of `sets`

```
[[0, 1, 2, 3], [1, 1, 2, 4], [2, 1, 2, 5]]
```

but after the second loop `sets` changed to

```
[[3, 2, 1, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3], [3, 2, 1, 0, 1, 1, 2, 4], [3, 2, 1, 0, 2, 1, 2, 5]]
```

I suspect the issue has something to do with copies and references. I've tried adding `.copy()` and slices in various places, but with the indexed sublists I haven't come across a combo that works. I'm running Python 3.10.6.

Thanks for looking!

Per suggested solution, `[list(range(reps)) for _ in range(n_sets)]` doesn't correctly replace the `list(range(reps)) * n_sets`, since it gives `[[0, 1, 2, 3], [0, 1, 2, 3], [0, 1, 2, 3]]` instead of
the desired `[0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3]`. Do I need to flatten, or is there a syntax with the `_` notation that gives me a single list?

Further update . . .
replacing

```
rep_list = list(range(reps)) * n_sets
```

with

```
rep_list_nest = [list(range(reps)) for _ in range(n_sets)]
rep_list = [i for sublist in rep_list_nest for i in sublist]
```

gives the **same** undesired result for `expanded_sets`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [List of lists changes reflected across sublists unexpectedly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240178/list-of-lists-changes-reflected-across-sublists-unexpectedly)

Comment: Maybe, this means the problem is in the *  n_sets instead of the inserts, which it where I thought is was. Not clear how to apply the _ notation from the one you linked to this, though.

Comment: After further exploration, no it does not, though it may be a piece of the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
expanded_sets = [item 
                 for item in sets
                 for i in range(reps)]
```

This list now contains the same element of `sets` four times in a row, followed by the next element repeated four times, and so on.

Creating copies of `item` fixes the issue:

```
expanded_sets = [item.copy() 
                 for item in sets
                 for i in range(reps)]
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##XZHBboMwEETv/oqRcsERQm2TXirl3Ft/AKHIgQ1YSmyEF9p8PfWaoDTlgBZ7d97O0N@48243zxt82okcDBwFpgYXGxj@jMlcRgo5/IBAHJS8cEBZvuZ4y7GrctzL/aN8ryqF@KgNTNNE0aQC9iBTdwjjKcm3drKuBXcEN15PNAiQO8OCgnXpRjoL5Y538IVcJqVWZ1lJugbjWsqWDv2RwKmlDJUurAs0cPaSI47Efb78NwbqKUKi9UDJlZwEsL1SUKk8YK/opzeuoWYll5bpWtS@v2UaApdv4af7dPDYRlR0JcDoIcYagm0lXUGzZevdankNxdf1GGdrkhCMiBayyzEldUgxZH@0NbZYLKt/6HtU22RqzePJTGmfglkpcrz8tn6wjp9n9Dz/Ag)

If you want a more pythonic approach, then recognize that the result is a product of two ranges, and your original `sets` all concatenated together:

```
from itertools import product

sets = [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 4], [1, 2, 5]]

expanded_sets = [[inner_counter, outer_counter] + sets_elem
                  for sets_elem, outer_counter, inner_counter in product(sets, range(len(sets)), range(4))]
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##XY7BDoJADETv@xU9snE9KHj0S8iGECi6CbSbUhL9@hWISPDUec3MZOJbn0z5uVlvSp3wAEFRlLkfIQyRRSEKt1OjxoyoI9yhLC8Org5y7@Ari13evDcGX7GmFtvqFwlEKFXDE831DnjSHT2cYDFW2OMAHctOf04Hh56ZtnXZEnEgNT0w65FWtnb7FNbOs6IE0uwwzqb0AQ)

Comment: Oh excellent, thank you. That makes sense. I knew I needed a copy somewhere but couldn't figure out the precise location.